# Reading data from a csv file Java

Tags: java, file, filereader, decision-tree

I want to read data from my dataset train.csv and I am trying to implement that using Java. My aim is to get this raw data in order to in the csv file in order to create a decision tree from this database. I have class DAO in which I implemented a method called extractTrainingData where I am writing the codes to read the data. This method is as follow.

```
public static BufferedReader exTractTraningData(File datafile, String ListOfCharacteristics) throws IOException {

    try {
        //create BufferedReader to read csv file
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datafile));

        String strLine = "";
        StringTokenizer st = null;

        int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;;

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while ((strLine = line) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            //break comma separated line using ","
            st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //display csv values
                tokenNumber++;
                System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber
                        + ", Token # " + tokenNumber
                        + ", Token : " + st.nextToken()
                         + ": " + line);
            }
            //reset token number
            tokenNumber = 0;;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I run the main class, it repeats the row repeatedly. I don't really know if I am doing it correctly. I tried to follow an online tutorial. Can anyone help me out? Thank you

Comment: You will probably run into more problems if you don't use a trusted API. I recommend https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/.

Comment: It is just for a group project, not a professional one but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: You call readLine() only once, before the loop...

Comment: thank you It is finally reading the dataset. But It is reading some null values as well. Is there any way to ignore every row in the dataset with a missing value (ie. a null value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your read call is outside of the while loop's test.

```
String strLine = "";

String line = reader.readLine();

while ((strLine = line) != null) {
```

Should probably be

```
String strLine = "";

while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

So that each iteration of the while loop operates on the result of a new read attempt

Comment: Thank you It is finally reading the dataset. But It is reading some null values as well. Is there any way to ignore every row in the dataset with a missing value (ie. a null value)?

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop never updates because you never update `line`.

What you probably want is

```
String strLine;
while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah It was a stupid mistake of mine :)).

Comment: It is finally reading the dataset. But It is reading some null values as well. Is there any way to ignore every row in the dataset with a missing value (ie. a null value)?

Comment: You could just check if it's null? `if(something == null){ /* do things differently */ }`

Comment: ok . Can a create a new boolean method to check if there for example?